# Bubble Sort objects

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

I need to sort my grocery inventory by name by using bubble sort.

Apparently, my code is not sorting the list by name.
BTW, the data stored inventory comes from a file input.

Here is my code.

```
public void sortInventoryByName() {
    //TODO: use bubble sort and compareTo
    int n = inventory.size();
    GroceryItem temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
            if (inventory.get(j).compareTo(inventory.get(j + 1)) > 0) {
                temp = inventory.get(i);
                inventory.set(i, inventory.get(i + 1));
                inventory.set(i + 1, temp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my compareTo method from my superclass (GroceryItem)

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    if(getClass() != o.getClass()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    else {
        GroceryItem other = (GroceryItem) o;
        return (this.name.compareTo(other.name));
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using index `j` to compare elements, but use `i` to swap elements

Comment: Oh, but when I replaces i with j, it is still not sorting by name

Comment: yes, I was able to fix my code with your advices. thank you so much.

Comment: @kenma05 if your question had been resolved, you could vote and accept helpful answers

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have some mismatch for comparing the right values.

There are two ways of implementing a bubble sort algorithm with two *for loops*.

Below made the first loop incremented `barrier` variable and second is decrementing `index`.

Thus with every iteration of the outer loop, the lowest value will be moved to the first place (like *the smallest bubble will be moved first*). The next iteration will skip this first element. And it will last till the list full list will be over.

Your example shows opposite behaviour -> with every iteration for the outer loop the highest element in a list is moved to the end.

It isn't so important how exactly do you want to iterate the inner for loop. The final sorted result is our aim.

Code snippet:

```
public void sortInventoryByName() {
    int n = inventory.size();
    for (int barrier = 0; barrier < n - 1; barrier++) {
        for (int index = n - 2; index >= barrier; index--) {
            if (inventory.get(index).compareTo(inventory.get(index + 1)) > 0) {
                GroceryItem temp = inventory.get(index);
                inventory.set(index, inventory.get(index + 1));
                inventory.set(index + 1, temp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your implementation of `compareTo()` should work fine. So, `inventory` list should be sorted correctly.

A few notices according to your code:

- you don't need to declare `temp` variable outside of loops. It is just a temporary variable for swapping two values. Inline declaration and usage will be enough.
- would suggest adding more meaningful names for loop variables instead of just `i` and `j`. It increases code readability and understanding in the future
- `else` block is redundant at `compareTo()`

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    if (getClass() != o.getClass()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    GroceryItem other = (GroceryItem) o;
    return this.name.compareTo(other.name);
}
```

Comment: "tried some to fix it" does not really help OP to understand why his attempt failed...

Comment: could you explain why you decrement on the second for loop, and did you mean to put   temp = inventory.get(index);

Comment: @kenma05 `.get(i)` it was a typo. Updated the answer. Let me know if it sorts well.

Comment: @catch23 The only difference between OP's code and your code is the index management. Please explain why so that the solution is understandable by everybody. This is explicitly asked by the OP in their previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

I filled in the missing parts of your code. You should read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also the link to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

The below code is the `GroceryItem` class which only contains a single member, i.e. `name`, which is the name of the grocery item. Since your question only deals with manipulating this member, I did not try to guess what other data the class needs.

Explanations after the code.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GroceryItem implements Comparable<GroceryItem> {
    private String  name;

    public GroceryItem(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override // java.lang.Comparable
    public int compareTo(GroceryItem other) {
        if (other == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            String otherName = other.getName();
            if (name == null) {
                if (otherName == null) {
                    return 0;
                }
                else {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            else {
                if (otherName == null) {
                    return 1;
                }
                else {
                    return name.compareTo(otherName);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override // java.lang.Object
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        boolean equal = false;
        if (other instanceof GroceryItem) {
            GroceryItem otherItem = (GroceryItem) other;
            if (name == null) {
                equal = otherItem.getName() == null;
            }
            else {
                equal = name.equals(otherItem.getName());
            }
        }
        return equal;
    }

    @Override // java.lang.Object
    public int hashCode() {
        return name == null ? 0 : name.hashCode();
    }

    @Override // java.lang.Object
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<GroceryItem> inventory = new ArrayList<>();
        inventory.add(new GroceryItem("apple"));
        inventory.add(new GroceryItem("pear"));
        inventory.add(new GroceryItem("banana"));
        inventory.add(new GroceryItem("orange"));
        inventory.add(new GroceryItem("beetroot"));
        inventory.add(new GroceryItem("onion"));
        inventory.add(new GroceryItem("lettuce"));
        inventory.add(new GroceryItem("carrot"));
        inventory.add(new GroceryItem("guava"));
        inventory.add(new GroceryItem("lychee"));
        inventory.add(new GroceryItem("kiwi"));

        int n = inventory.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++) {
                if (inventory.get(j).compareTo(inventory.get(j+1)) > 0) {
                    // swap inventory[j+1] and inventory[j]
                    GroceryItem temp = inventory.get(j);
                    inventory.set(j, inventory.get(j+1));
                    inventory.set(j+1, temp);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The above code creates a `List` of `GroceryItem` objects that contains eleven elements. After populating the `List`, the *bubble sort* is performed in the two, nested `for` loops. Finally the sorted `List` is printed.

Note that class `GroceryItem` also implements method `toString()` so as to make the output human-readable when printing an instance of `GroceryItem`.

If, in future, you need to use `GroceryItem` as the key for a `java.util.HashMap`, then `GroceryItem` will need to override method `hashCode()` and if a class overrides method `hashCode()` then it should also override method `equals()`. Hence that is why the above code includes those overridden methods. Note that none of those methods – `equals()`, `hashCode()` and `toString()` – are required for the *bubble sort*.

The oputput when running the above code is:

```
[apple, banana, beetroot, carrot, guava, kiwi, lettuce, lychee, onion, orange, pear]
```

Comment: By adding all those `null` checks in the `compareTo` method, you're adding a layer of complexity that is very likely not needed by the user. Also, the OP never mentions any `null` issue, so you're adding that level of complexity for nothing. Finally, what makes you think that `null`s should be first? Maybe they should come last. Personally I was confused when I saw your `null`-check section because you gave it such an importance that I was sure I missed something, but after double-checking, no, I haven't missed anything. For `null`-comparison, use Guava's `Ordering.nullsFirst()/nullsLast()`.